# How to sort objects of an array by same order of objects of another array where need to compare multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, logic

**Updated requirement on 04/06/2021:**

I have two array of objects, arrX and arrY. Need to sort the objects of 'arrY' same as the order of 'arrX'. What is the shortest or best way?

**Note:** Objects which has type other than types of arrX should got to the bottom ie. "type: 'X'" here.

```
const arrX = [
     {type: 'C', category: 'CAT2'},
     {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1},
     {type: 'B', category: 'CAT3'},
    ]    

const arrY = [
             {type: 'B', category: 'CAT3'},
             {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1'},
             {type: 'C', category: 'CAT2'},
             {type: 'B', category: 'CAT3'},
             {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1'},
             {type: 'X', category: 'CAT4'},
             {type: 'B', category: 'CAT2'},
             {type: 'X', category: 'CAT4'},
             {type: 'X', category: 'CAT5'},
             {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1'},
             {type: 'C', category: 'CAT2'}, 
    ]
```

**Should Be sorted as:**

```
const arrX = [
     {type: 'C', category: 'CAT2'},
     {type: 'C', category: 'CAT2'},
     {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1'},
     {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1'},
     {type: 'A', category: 'CAT1'},
     {type: 'B', category: 'CAT3'},
     {type: 'B', category: 'CAT3'},
     {type: 'X', category: 'CAT4'},
     {type: 'B', category: 'CAT2'},
     {type: 'X', category: 'CAT4'},
     {type: 'X', category: 'CAT5'}, 
    ]
```

Comment: Did you try using `arrY.sort`?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+sort+objects+by+property) of [Sort array of objects by string property value](/q/1129216/4642212) and [duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+sort+array+according+to+another+array) of [Javascript - sort array based on another array](/q/13304543/4642212) (use the top-voted answer (the one with the simple `indexOf` comparison), not the accepted one). It’s easier if you had `const arrX = [ "C", "A", "B" ]` insead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I don't think it's duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the order with a default value for unknown types.

```js
const
    arrX = [{ type: 'C' }, { type: 'A' },  { type: 'B' }],
    arrY = [{ type: 'B' }, { type: 'A' }, { type: 'C'  }, { type: 'B' }, { type: 'A' }, { type: 'X' }, { type: 'B' }, { type: 'X' }, { type: 'X' }, { type: 'A'  }, { type: 'C' }],
    order = Object.fromEntries(arrX.map(({ type }, i) => [type, i + 1]));
    
order.default = Number.MAX_VALUE;

arrY.sort((a, b) => (order[a.type] || order.default) - (order[b.type] || order.default));

console.log(arrY);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: your one is the good one till now, but it may not work if we need to compare 2 properties from objects of the 'arrX' like [{type: 'A', category: 'xyz'}, {type: 'A', category: 'mnp'}];

Comment: how would you like to compare the other property?

Answer (score 0):

I would add something that would be comparable in `arrX`. In the following, I have added an `index` to `arrY` to be more distinguishable.

```
const addIndex = (list) => list.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, index }));
const targetIndex = (targets, element) => {
  const found = targets.find((item) => item.type === element.type);
  return found ? found.index : null;
};

const sortByType = (target, source) => {
  const targetWithId = addIndex(target);
  const sourceWithId = addIndex(source);

  sourceWithId.sort((a, b) => {
    const indexA = targetIndex(targetWithId, a);
    const indexB = targetIndex(targetWithId, b);
    if (indexA === indexB) {
      return 0;
    }

    if (indexA === null) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (indexB === null) {
      return -1;
    }

    return indexA - indexB;
  });

  return sourceWithId;
};

result = sortByType(arrX, arrY);
```

which would yield:

```
[
  { type: 'C', index: 2 },
  { type: 'C', index: 10 },
  { type: 'A', index: 1 },
  { type: 'A', index: 4 },
  { type: 'A', index: 9 },
  { type: 'B', index: 0 },
  { type: 'B', index: 3 },
  { type: 'B', index: 6 },
  { type: 'X', index: 5 },
  { type: 'X', index: 7 },
  { type: 'X', index: 8 }
]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but it seems too complex.

Comment: @Paveloosha I have explicitly expanded the logic for you to understand better. The complexity seems to be just that I and adding the `index` key to both array for you to understand how the sorting works. This proposition allows you to expand if you have multiple properties to compare with, as you suggested in the comment of the other answer.